# New to Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm completely new to visual basic and somewhat new to programming in general. I'm trying to teach myself how to use visual basic because I was told it was easier to learn. My question is how do I connect an execute button to a text box to calculate a simple math problem? Do I double click the button I want to make the execution and then put in the code? Can someone give me a simple sample code that when you enter a number in a text box and press the execute button, the number entered would be multiplied by another number like 2 or whatever and then be displayed in another box? I just need a way to understand how the coding works and connects the gui buttons and text boxes so I can understand it better. I'm good and learning on my own when I see how things work and then I can put things together and figure them out. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps start following some of these: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/

Comment: Just Google for *vb.net windows forms tutorial* there are many.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it...

...of course the devil is in the details.  The main problem you'll run into in this scenario is that your TextBox holds a **String**, but you want to manipulate it as a Number.  First you need to convert the string to a number, then do the math.  This also allows you to determine if the String in the TextBox is not a number, such as if the user entered "Unicorns are real!" in it:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim strInput As String = TextBox1.Text
        If Integer.TryParse(strInput, x) Then
            Dim result As Integer = x * 2
            Label1.Text = x.ToString & " * 2 = " & result.ToString
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Invalid Integer: " & strInput
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```